# Trying to create a load screen in Kotlin(Android)

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to make a simple load screen in a app using kotlin

Instead of just displaying a text, I want to play a sound and show an image for like, 3 seconds.

I created a layout to set for 3 seconds using `Thread.sleep`, but it didn't work.

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Thank you!

```
class MatrixActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.loading_activity_matrix)

        Thread.sleep(3000)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_matrix)

        A00.setOnClickListener { sendCommand("00000")}
        B00.setOnClickListener { sendCommand("00100")}
        C00.setOnClickListener { sendCommand("00200")}
        D00.setOnClickListener { sendCommand("00300")}
        E00.setOnClickListener { sendCommand("00400")}
        F00.setOnClickListener { sendCommand("00500")}
        G00.setOnClickListener { sendCommand("00600")}
        H00.setOnClickListener { sendCommand("00700")}
```

Comment: You can’t sleep in the main (UI) thread. Use `postRunnable` to create a delayed action that will happen on the main thread. But also keep in mind that users absolutely hate load screens, so why create an artificial one?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, nobody likes load screens, but this particular activity needs do have this one. When the person hit the button, a command is sent do an Arduino via Bluetooth, and this comand takes like 3 seconds to perform its action. Instead of just showing a boring "Loading..." screen, it would be more useful e it was a tip.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Kotlins coroutines, you can use

```
runBlocking {
    delay(3000) //waits for 3s
}
```

in place of `Thread.sleep(3000)` to let a thread sleep for the given amount of milliseconds. If you need help setting up coroutines, or need further information, great explanations are on the Kotlin website: [Your first coroutine with Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/coroutines/coroutines-basic-jvm.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you describe more?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include some more information. I don't have experience with Android development, but I hope what I've added helps.